# Parameter / CascadingParameter not updating object

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I want to update a `TodoItem` in a child component `TodoComponent` passing a `EventCallback`.

In my `TodoPage.razor.cs` I've implemented an update method:

```cs
public async void UpdateTodo(TodoItem todoItem)
{
    await Http.PutAsJsonAsync("todo", todoItem);
    await RefreshTodos();
}
```

And then I'm trying to pass to the `TodoComponent` that is responsible to render the object

```cs
@foreach (var item in @TodoItems)
{
    <div class="row">
            <CascadingValue Value=@item Name="TodoItem">
                <TodoComponent UpdateCallback="@(async () => UpdateTodo(item))">
                </TodoComponent>
            </CascadingValue>
    </div>
}
```

`TodoComponent.razor`

```cs
@inherits ListOfTodos.Client.Components.TodoComponentBase
<div class="input-group col-12">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="@TodoItem.IsDone" onclick="@UpdateCallback">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@TodoItem.TaskName" oninput="@UpdateCallback" />
    </div>

    <div class="input-group-append">
        <input type="date" @bind="@TodoItem.DueDate" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Aditional info:

```cs
public async Task RefreshTodos()
{
    TodoItems = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<TodoItem>>("todo");
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

```cs
public class TodoComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "TodoItem")]
    public TodoItem TodoItem { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<TodoItem> UpdateCallback { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

}
```

**When I call the `UpdateCallback` though `onchange` or `oninput` the `TodoItem`comes like if it wasn't updated at all, I don't know if the binding is working as I intend it to do.**

How do I properly pass the object to the child component and have it update correctly?

This is the github repo: https://github.com/DgoNeves/Blazor.ListOfTodos
It works in memory so you don't need any database to run it.

Edit: I don't exactly know why this happens but apparently the controller call is behing for some reason.
[image: Blazor Update Behind]

Comment: call `StateHasChanged()`

Comment: I've added some aditional info to show that I'm already calling stateHasChanged, although it has nothing to do with the UI, because when I make a change in the UI the problem is that the object is not updated, therefore on the call to the API It is "updated" to the same state

Comment: Just, why to you use a cascading parameter in this case and not a classic parameter ?

Comment: I've tried both, neither are working as I was expecting

Comment: May be because the update is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out!

`@bind="@TodoItem.TaskName"` executes by default `onChange`

`onInput` apparently happens before the `onChange` so in the screenshot when I get 1 character behind it means that it did not update the `TodoItem.TaskName` because that's the next step.

If I really want to call the API on every keystroke I need to change it to:

`@bind-value="@TodoItem.TaskName" @bind-value:event="oninput" onchange="@UpdateCallback"`

This way I change the binding to happen `onInput`and I call the `UpdateCallback` `onChange`.
Because the `onInput happens first` I get the updated value on `onChange` therefore passing the correct value.

Source from where I've found this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15554
He had exactly the same error as I did

Answer (score 2):

`StateHasChanged();` Only update current page with Childs, does not affect parent component.

For communication between child-parent component use must `EventCallback`

```
<CascadingValue Value="yourModel">
    <ChildComponent OnStateHasChanged="OnStateHasChanged" />
</CascadingValue>
```

**ParentComponent**

```
private void OnStateHasChanged()
{
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

**Child Component**

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback OnStateHasChanged { get; set; }

private async Task OnUpdatedChild()
{
      await OnStateHasChanged.InvokeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just get your issue. It's your `UpdateTodo` method :
An async method must return a Task or a ValueTask. Update your code with :

```cs
public async Task UpdateTodo(TodoItem todoItem)
{
    await Http.PutAsJsonAsync("todo", todoItem);
    await RefreshTodos();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work the behavior is exactly the same with "Task"

Comment: @DiogoNeves did you check the browser consol log ?

Comment: @DiogoNeves - Still, Task is better. The lambda you use to call this is another `async void`, harder to see. They are fire&forget, you have no control over the order of actions here.

Comment: @aguafrommars nothing in console.log;

Comment: @HenkHolterman It might be a racing condition actually, let me see what I can do with that.

Comment: @DiogoNeves that : `@(async () => UpdateTodo(item))` not seems correct too. if you use async you should await.

Comment: So, I've made all the changes in my code base and still no good result, although I've found something.
If I change the `TodoComponent.razor` from from `oninput` to `onblur` it works as expected! But I have to change focus and I wanted to be able to do `oninput`